# What is known about iterative behavior of this function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $p$ be a function that sums divisors of some natural number but which does not sum that number.

For example we have $p(12)=1+2+3+4+6=16$.

We can take that $p(1)=1$ to avoid possible difficulties later.

Perfect numbers are fixed points of this function, and for primes we have $p(q)=1$ and $p(p(q)))=1$ if $q$ is a prime, so, on perfects and primes, this function has a very simple behavior.

It would be nice to know how this function behaves with respect to iteration.

So we define $p^{\circ}_k(n)=p(...p(n))$ ( $p$ applied $k$ times successively).

For, for example $12$, we have $p(12)=16$ and $p(16)=15$ and $p(15)=9$ and $p(9)=4$ and $p(4)=3$ and $p(3)=1$, so we have $p^{\circ}_l(12))=1$ for every $l\geq 6$.

If we take some number and apply $p$ to that number successively then two types of behavior can arise:

1) we run into a loop of length $\geq 1$

2) we escape into an infinity

Because looping seems hard to detect, I would like to know something more about 2).

At first, a question naturally arises:

Is there some natural number for which successive appliance of a function $p$ never loops? That is, phrased differently, is there some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that we have that $\{p(n),p^{\circ}_2,p^{\circ}_3,...\}$ is unbounded?

Comment: You might be interested in [amicable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers) and variants on that idea.

Comment: These are known as [aliquot sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AliquotSequence.html) and their behavior is not known.  It is conjectured (Catalan) that they are all bounded, but this has not been shown (and may well be false).

Comment: @lulu I also think that they are all bounded.

Comment: Well, you are in good company.  But there are very small numbers ($276$ is one,  if memory serves) for which even modern computers have not been able to settle the point.   For whatever it's worth, I am agnostic on the matter.

Comment: @lulu $276$ is correct, according to the link you posted earlier.

Comment: @lulu I tend to believe that after enough iterations every number that does not form a loop will hit a prime, that is why I think that they are all bounded.

Comment: @lulu I am also sceptical, unless there is some evidence indicating the truth of the conjecture. Is this the case ?

Comment: @Peter  Not any persuasive evidence, no.  Indeed there is also a conjecture, from Guy and Selfridge, that would say that nearly all aliquot sequences that start from an even number are unbounded.  So far, the jury is still out.

Comment: [here](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/firstfunctionbcmit.pdf) are some notes that (briefly) summarize the state of knowledge.  Apparently, about a third of the even numbers below $10^6$ are currently unknown...though, again, it is not clear what that means.

Comment: @Right why would a sequence hit a prime though? If we are speaking based on gut feelings alone, primes become less and less common as the numbers grow larger. So its very believable to find an (more or less) increasing aliquot sequence which never hits a prime number.

Comment: @Hamed Exactly, unless some properties prevent a fast increasing aliquot sequence. If this cannot be ruled out somehow (I am not an expert for aliquot sequences, maybe it can be ruled out) , a reasonable guess would be to expect many unbounded sequences.

Comment: @lulu If a third of the even numbers upto $10^6$ are unknown, we apparently know not much about aliquot-sequences.

Comment: @Peter Should we make a chat-room for aliquot sequences and start from somewhere in order to prove something?

Comment: @Peter  Exactly.  It seems extremely hard to get any sort of a handle on the problem.

Comment: @Right Why not ? Could be interesting and perhaps entertaining.

Comment: @Peter OK, you create it and call me in and I will come. I never created one and do not know how to create it and send an invitation.

Comment: I have created the room, but I do not know how to invite someone. (I did not find a button "invite")

Comment: @Peter Maybe there is no such button. What is the name of a room?

Comment: Just "aliquot sequences"

Comment: @lulu Want to join to our chat ?

Comment: @Peter  At some point, maybe.  Running out the door now.

Answer (score 2):

The Catalan conjecture (sometimes called the Catalan–Dickson conjecture), is that every aliquot sequence ends either at $1$ or in a finite loop (reaching a perfect, amicable, or sociable number).

It is currently an open question.  For example [this talk from 2016](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~hadi/2016-09-29-aliquot_sequences.pdf) by A. S. Mosunov, "What do we know about aliquot sequences?", explains the conjecture of Guy and Selfridge that an unbounded [aliquot sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sequence) exists:

> We do not know any $n$ such that the aliquot sequence starting
>   at $n$ is unbounded. However, up to $1000$ there are $12$ possible candidates:
>   $276,306,396,552,564,660,696,780,828,888,966,996$. The aliquot sequences starting at $276,552,564,660$ and $966$ were studied by Derrik Lehmer.

These latter cases are known as the [Lehmer Five](http://www.aliquot.de/lehmer.htm).

> **Guy-Selfridge Counter Conjecture.** There are infinitely
>   many aliquot sequences that are unbounded.
>
> **Guy-Selfridge Heuristics.** Most of the aliquot sequences
>   starting with even number are unbounded, while most of the
>   aliquot sequences starting with an odd number are bounded.

This is a pretty remarkable claim, but see Guy and Selfridge (1975) [What drives an aliquot sequence?](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1975-29-129/S0025-5718-1975-0384669-X/S0025-5718-1975-0384669-X.pdf) for some reasoning.